# C# Regular Expression with multiple criteria

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a regular expression that full-fill the following criteria:

1. value will be a number of exactly 6 digits
2. no consecutive 6 digits allow (e.g. 123456, 654321, 234567 etc. not allow)
3. not more than 2 repeating digits allow (e.g. 111234, 123444, 123334 not allow, but 112345, 123455, 123345 is allow)

i'm trying to write this regular expression, but failed.
note that, i can write regular expression for that criteria individually, but i need a combined regular expression.
Plz help me anyone as soon as possible.

i got a solution that full-fill only my first & second criteria:

```
string re = @"(?x)
        ^
        # fail if...
        (?!
            # repeating numbers
            0{3,}|1{3,}|2{3,}|3{3,}|4{3,}|5{3,}|6{3,}|7{3,}|8{3,}|9{3,}$
            |
            # sequential ascending
            (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5} \d $
            |
            # sequential descending
            (?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $
        )
        # match any other combinations of 6 digits
        \d{6}
        $
    ";
```

But, i need complete solution (a combined regular expression) that full-fill my 3 criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the first condition to:

```
\d*(\d)(?:\d*\1){2,}\d*$
```

`(\d)(?:\d*\1){2,}` will match more than 2 repeating digits (consecutive or not) and the `\d*` allow for any number of digits before or after the repeating part.

Meaning your new regex becomes:

```
string re = @"(?x)
        ^
        # fail if...
        (?!
            # repeating numbers
            \d*(\d)(?:\d*\1){2,}\d*$
            |
            # sequential ascending
            (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5} \d $
            |
            # sequential descending
            (?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $
        )
        # match any other combinations of 6 digits
        \d{6}
        $
    ";
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/gR2uE2)

Comment: ur solution full-fill my requirements partially, not completely. for example, for 111456 it shows invalid, but for 114561 it shows valid (actually this number is invalid because here total three 1's exist). pls help me.

Comment: @Kaysar Oh, okay, I'll try to tweak it :)

Comment: Yes, i tried with ur edited code. but not work for all test cases (that i already mention ago). i think little bit correction needed. pls try.

Comment: @Kaysar I don't understand. Which number is it incorrectly taking?

Comment: for 114561 it shows valid ,actually this number is invalid because here more then two 1's exist

Comment: @Kaysar It's showing invalid for me. Are you sure you are using the edited code?

Comment: sorry Jerry, it was my mistake. now i tried with ur edited code & got exact result. thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

Try the program [regex coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/). There you can analyze the regex better and faster and make it work, before you plug it into the C# program.

If you don't like that long regex you can always make 3 regex objects and or them together.